# Applying animations to objects in openGL

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, 3d

I have stumbled upon a problem here while writing a program in which I am animating shapes using openGL.

Currently in the program, I am creating some shapes, with the following snippet

```
for(int i=50;i<=150;i=i+50){
for(int j=50;j<=750;j=j+200){
//Draw rectangle shape at position(j,i); //shape has additional capability for animations }
}
```

which gives me this output:

[image]

Now, I have to resize these rectangles and move them all to another position. I have the  final target `Point` for the first rectangle `rectangle at position[0][0]` where it should be moved. However, when I animate the size of these rectangles with something like

`rectangle.resize(newWidth, newHeight, animationTime);`

the rectangle for obvious reasons do not stick together, and I get something like:

[image]

I am looking for something like `Grouping` which can bind these shapes together, so that even when different animations like resize (and motion etc.) are applied, the vertices or the boundaries should be touching together.

Note that `Grouping` is the main thing here. I might have a requirement in the future in which I would have to group the two rectangles in the last column, where independent animations (like rotations) already happening on them. So, I picture this something like a `plane/container` having these two rectangle and that `plane/container` itself can be animated for position etc. I am fine with algorithm/concept and not the code.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such common thing in opengl, you have to always manage rendering of your graphics objects all alone..

Comment: @Sorceror: The other way of looking at this question would be to think of two animations being applied to a certain shape. (for eg: a rectangle being rotated on Y-axis, and that already animated rectangle itself further being rotated along X-axis.) This is similar to PowerPoint animations which can be applied simaltaneously to an object. Looking in that direction, does it help anyhow on how to apply two animations to a single object?

Comment: if you want to apply more animation to one object, the best way is to use matrix transformations, then you can apply as many transformations as you will one to even single object, just by multiplying them (transformation matrices) together.. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

Answer (score 0):

Instead of animating the geometry on the CPU, animate scale/position matrices on the CPU and leave the transformation of the geometry to the vertex shader via the MVP matrix. Use one and the same scale matrix for all the rectangles. (Or two matrices, if your scale factor is different in X and Y).

PS. Here's an example:

```
float sc = 0;

void init()
{
  glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity ();
}

void on_each_frame()
{
  // do other things 

  // draw pulsating rectangles
  sc += 0.02;
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glPushMatrix();
  glScalef((float)sin(sc) + 1.5f);
  // draw rectangles as usual, **without** scaling them
  glPopMatrix();

  // do other things
}
```

Comment: The way I am handling animations here in my program is tweening the values in each frame and using those tweened values in the drawing the rectangle `glRectangle(x, y, tweenedX, tweenedY)`. So when tweenedX and tweenedY, I get a scaled rectangle. I didn't get your solution fully. It would be great if you could add more detail to this, as till now I have been following more towards the c++ rather than the openGL (being a rather starter in openGL)

Answer (score 0):

Think about implementing a 'DrawableAnimatableObject' which is a high level 3D object that is able to animate and draw itself, and contains your polygons (multiple rectangles in your case) as internal data. See the following incomplete code to give you an idea:

```
class DrawableAnimatableObject {
private:
    Mesh *mesh;
    Vector3 position;
    Quaternion orientation;
    Vector3 scale;
    Matrix transform;

public:
    DrawableAnimatableObject();
    ~DrawableAnimatableObject();

    //update the object properties for the next frame.
    //it updates the scale, position or orientation of your
    //object to suit your animation.
    void update();  

    //Draw the object. 
    //This function converts scale, orientation and position 
    //information into proper OpenGL matrices and passes them 
    //to the shaders prior to drawing the polygons, 
    //therefore no need to resize the polygons individually.
    void draw();

    //Standard set-get;
    void setPosition(Vector3 p);
    Vector3 getPosition();
    void setOrientation(Quaternion q);
    Quaternion getOrientation();
    void setScale(float f);
    Vector3 getScale();
};
```

In this code, Mesh is a data structure that contains your polygons. Simply put, it can be a vertex-face list, or a more complicated structure like half-edge. The DrawableAnimatableObject::draw() function should look something like this:

```
DrawableAnimatableObject::draw() {

    transform = Matrix::CreateTranslation(position) * Matrix::CreateFromQuaternion(orientation) * Matrix::CreateScale(scale);

    // in modern openGL this matrix should be passed to shaders.
    // in legacy OpenGL you will apply this matrix with:
    glPushMatrix();
    glMultMatrixf(transform);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    //...
    // Draw your rectangles here.
    //...
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
}
```